# jasperreport : display list size of subdataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to display the size of the list of my subreport passed in parameter in my report. Here is how I define subdataset and the variable :

```
<subDataset name="collabsStructureDebutList" uuid="4fb1b45d-1872-489c-b0d9-9fb569cf77ca">
    <field name="nomCollaborateur" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nomCommercial" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dateEntree" class="java.time.LocalDate"/>
    <field name="dateSortie" class="java.time.LocalDate"/>
</subDataset>

<parameter name="collabsStructureDebutList" class="java.util.List"/>
    
<variable name="collaStructureListSize" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{collabsStructureDebutList})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

When I display the report, the variable collabsStructureDebutList has the value 1, whereas it should have 16.

Comment: Why not to use `$P{collabsStructureDebutList}.size()`? BTW, no need to use `calculation="Count"`

Comment: It keeps displaying the value 1 with size()

Comment: You should post small *jrxml* and Java snippet to reproduce the issue

Comment: I didnt see your comment on calculation="Count", I removed it and now it works fine. thx